Вопрос по функции Isblank() класса Range
Скажите пожалуйста почему функция isBlank() в следующем фрагменте кода на js в гугл таблицах для ячейки в которой записано значение пустой строки ("") также возвращает true, как и для ячейки в которой вообще ничего не было введено? Хотя например, если я в ячейку B29 ввожу следующую формулу:
=ЕПУСТО(A29), то она мне возвращает TRUE только если в ячейке ничего не введено, а для пустой строки она возвращает FALSE. Как мне именно из скрипта отличить значение пустой строки "" от заведомо пустой ячейки (когда она не содержит никакого значения)?
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange('A29');
   var value = range.getValue();

  
   if (range.isBlank())
     Logger.log('Значение не определено');


Добавил в ячейку пустую строку через setValue('') И формула ISBLANK() и код range.isBlank() выдает TRUE

Спасибо! Я тоже с помощью SetValue('')  и даже SetValue("") установил значение в ячейке и  ЕПУСТО() выдало TRUE, но допустим если я вручную ввожу значение ячейки через строку формул следующим образом ="", то в самой ячейке ничего не отображается (хотя как только я делаю данную ячейку активной, то в строке формул отображается =""), но функция ЕПУСТО на нее FALSE выдает.
